# Error special characters Google Sheets api v4 with ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra, google-sheets-api, google-api-ruby-client

When I add values with special characters (example: ñ) to a Google Sheets api v4 receive this error

I use Ruby 2.5.7 with Sinatra on Windows

This is my code :

```
# encoding: UTF-8
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8 

require "google_drive"
require 'google/apis/sheets_v4'

values = [
   ["10000001", "prueba ñ", 100],
]

value_range = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new(values: values)
result = service.append_spreadsheet_value(spreadsheet_id,
                                          range_name,
                                          value_range,
                                          value_input_option: 'RAW')
```

> ERROR on service.append_spreadsheet_value :
>
> Encoding::CompatibilityError - incompatible character encodings: CP850 and UTF-8

Comment: Send the correct encoding.... You might need to encode as utf8 before sending

Comment: values = [ ["10000001", "prueba \u00F1", 100],]  it does not work / "prueba ñ uno".force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8) it does not work

Comment: The encoding is correct at the beginning: # encoding: UTF-8
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding :: UTF_8. /// Also :
text.force_encoding (:: Encoding :: UTF_8) /// "prueba \ u00F1" .encode ('iso-8859-1'). encode ('utf-8') /// Iconv.iconv ('iso-8859-1', 'UTF-8', "prueba\ u00F1"), etc.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Ruby, but if you just use the `Try It API` of https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append - you can directly append your data including `ñ` without any encoding, so maybe in Ruby you can also try it without encoding?

Comment: if that is exactly the api that I am using, from developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ it works fine but doing it from Ruby 2.5.7 passing a text with special characters without any encoding does not work and with encoding either

Comment: How can you control with `Encoding.default` at what step exactly the encoding takes place and what will be encoded?